# Split command line to arguments

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I need to launch an external Java process. Arguments are formed elsewhere and are passed to me as a single string. I need to find a certain "-D" key  and update its value before actually running a process.

Example:

```
java -Dosgi.framework.extensions="foo bar" "fdf -Dosgi.framework.extensions=bim bom"
```

Should become:

```
java -Dosgi.framework.extensions="bar" "fdf -Dosgi.framework.extensions=bim bom"
```

How do I properly tokenize arguments? Obviously splitting by space is not  an option.
I'd like to use a plugin from Eclipse infrastructure, if possible.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1200054/10077

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin.parseArguments](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/debug/core/DebugPlugin.html#parseArguments(java.lang.String)). Unfortunately is escapes the result and I'm not sure why and how does that affects the final result. Nevertheless it is passing my tests.